# AngularJs php rest API secured communication

Tags: angularjs, rest, security

I am looking for a secured communication between my AngularJs client and PHP REST API. The communication should be highly secured to match the enterprise standards.

Could you please direct me to the right website? I am even ready to buy a premium code/script

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it to use a JWT token for secure communications. On authentication, a token will be generated and issued to the client. This will be sent every time with HTTP requests to the Web API. The API can then authenticate the request based on the token. Please visit 
[JWT Tokens](https://jwt.io/) website. You will get samples on how to implement it on bot client and server. It also has some libraries which will help you with the integration on the server side.

Comment: Whenever there is a AJAX call to the API, the payload is fully visible in the console. Is there a way to hide what is being sent to the API and what received?

Comment: @VinodNadar Why do you need to hide the payload? The console is a part of the browser. Browser always knows what is being sent and received. I really don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve to hide the payload?

Comment: I am worried because if someone has the payload format and the token from the server, he can easily hit my API using Postman and make any changes to the data which he is not supposed to. He can even access the data that he should not be accessing

Comment: @VinodNadar  How and why would anyone have access to your server? In worst case, if anyone gets access to the server, dont you think they can already do anything on the server. They wont bother to look at the client side.